# How to get html field data in Mongodb (Mongoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, mongoose

I want to update some data in MongoDB by sending form.
So for example I have form:

```
<form action='/update' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='username'>
    <input type='submit' value='send'>    
</form>
```

And have code:

```
router.post('/change', function (req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1}, {$set:{name:"Garry"}}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
        }
        console.log(doc);
    }
);
```

How to insert value from my "username" field, instead "Garry"? How can I declare my 'usernamename' variable in mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get POST parameters, you’ll need the ExpressJS body-parser package.

```
$ npm install body-parser --save
```

Once it has been added to the package.json, you have to configure it in your server.js file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

The form data sent by POST method to the server is received in body. So your body will have all the data you need to either save, update or whatever operation you want to do. You will receive it req.body.variableName like this.

```
router.post('/change', function (req, res) {
var username = req.body.username;
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1}, {$set:{name:username}}, {new: true}, function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }
    console.log(doc);
}
);
```